# $product->getWeight() returning always NULL

Tags: magento-1.8, product-attribute, product-collection

Any idea why a code can stop returning getWeight? (but still returns SKU)
It's so basic I don't know what can be happening.

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->setStore('xxx');
foreach ($products as $p) {
  $sku = $p->getSku(); //<-- OK
  $weight = $p->getWeight(); //<-- Always null
}
```

No suspicious log or exception. 
Still using 1.8 for a complex reason.
I'm executing this code in a php apart in order to refill a custom field using weight value.

Comment: can you confirm product has value for weight in admin panel?

Comment: yes, they have. I'm executing this code in a php apart in order to refill a custom field using weight value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `weight` attribute to your product collection first, try this:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('weight');

foreach ($products as $p) {
  var_dump($p->getWeight());
}
```

Comment: No idea why it was working before without that select, but Thank you!

Comment: @MarioM. maybe changed "Used in Product Listing" in manage attribute settings?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you can see the weight when you load the product directly

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product->setStoreId($storeId);
$product->load($product_id);

$prod_weight = $product->getWeight();
```

If this works you may need to specifically add the weight attribute to your collection.

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->setStoreId($_storeId)
->addAttributeToSelect('weight');
```